# AWS Serverless app - tests wont connect to DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I created a sample serverless blog project in Visual Studio 2017.  If I try to execute the unit test, it fails with :

```
MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean System.Reflection.Assembly.op_Equality(System.Reflection.Assembly, System.Reflection.Assembly)'.
```

This happens when creating the DynamoDBClient - not even trying to access anything at that point.  i.e.:

```
this.DDBClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
```

I created my own project based on this template with the same result.
I tried switching the test project to core 1.1 but then got a different error about log4net, which I dont have referenced.

Has anyone got unit tests to work ?  Not sure if it's a DynamoDB client problem or something more general.

Update:
This only seems to be failing in Visual Studio 2017.  If I run using the command line:

```
dotnet test
```

then it fails with credential problems, which is much easier to understand.

Im beginning to think that Linux and Node is a much more attractive option than this windows s**t.

Comment: Did you provide the access keys to AWS SDK configuration?

Comment: Probably not, but it's not getting that far... see my update.

Comment: Oh and it works fine on my home machine so I guess there's something in my work environment that is munting this.

Comment: I would prefer NodeJS also since there is serverless framework available where it will simplify most of the heavy liftings for you.